# How to test the settimeout function inside the ngOnInit using jasmine

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, karma-jasmine

I need to write a test for a ngOnInit function that has a setTimeout() call inside, but i can't find how i should do I am new to jasmine test cases,please help

app.component.ts:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
     if(sessionStorage.getItem("login") === "loggedIN"){
      this.isNav = true;
      this.isUserLogged = false;
      this.loginservice.isLoggedIn = true;
      setTimeout(()=>{
        const isHidden = this.eleRef.nativeElement.querySelector(".header-nav-items");
        isHidden.removeAttribute("hidden");
        this.eleRef.nativeElement.querySelector(".]navigation").classList.remove("theme-black");
        this.eleRef.nativeElement.querySelector(".horizontal-right").classList.remove("profile");
        this.eleRef.nativeElement.querySelector(".horizontal-right").classList.remove("theme-black");
      },500);
     
     }

    }
```

app.component.spec.ts :

```
describe('AppComponent', () => {
  let component: AppComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [ RouterTestingModule ],
      schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA ],
      declarations: [ AppComponent ]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create the app', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.componentInstance;
    expect(app).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

I could manage to write still here.

Comment: add the angular tag to this

Comment: I think a better approach would be to do away with setTimeout function and move  the code inside it to `AfterViewInit` life cycle hook

Comment: @OwenKelvin, I tried with the AfterViewInit but it was working only by adding the settimeout it was working or else can show a approach by posting the code using the afterviewinit thanks

Answer (score 0):

Consider the code

```
const isHidden = this.eleRef.nativeElement.querySelector(".header-nav-items");
isHidden.removeAttribute("hidden");
this.eleRef.nativeElement.querySelector(".]navigation").classList.remove("theme-black");
this.eleRef.nativeElement.querySelector(".horizontal-right").classList.remove("profile");
this.eleRef.nativeElement.querySelector(".horizontal-right").classList.remove("theme-black");
```

This code is simply toggling classes, therefore we can make use of class binding to achieve this. Something like `[class.theme-black]='isLoggedIn'`

In TS File we will then remain with

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  if(sessionStorage.getItem("login") === "loggedIN") {
    this.isNav = true;
    this.isUserLogged = false;
    this.loginservice.isLoggedIn = true;
  }
}
```

We can further improve the above code to

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.isNav = sessionStorage.getItem("login") === "loggedIN";
  this.isUserLogged = !this.isNav;
  this.loginservice.isLoggedIn = this.isNav;
}
```

In Your HTML

```
  <div class='header-nav-items' *ngIf='!isNav'></div>
  <div class='navigation' [class.theme-black]='!isNav'></div>
  <div class='horizontal-right'[class.profile]='!isNav' [class.theme-black]='!isNav'></div>
```

The above may not be answering the problem of testing the setTimeout function but it is a better way to achieve the above testing